# Real life example of multithreaded merge sort

Tags: multithreading, mergesort

I have been working for a project **MULTI THREADED MERGE SORT**.
I have one real example of this project is sorted of our files in Desktop.
i-e : sort by name,sort by size 
Can anyone tell me more real life examples of merge sort ?

Answer (score 0):

In reality, merge sort is very important in distributed file system and distributed computing (more than multi-thread).  Some sort of multi-way merge sort can effectively utilize the secondary storage to sort very large files which can not fit in memory.